# Perl: Reading from file and saving into an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I had got a script in Perl and my task is to do some changes in it. This of course means to understand which part does exactly what. I am not familiar with Perl language but I tried to read through some tutorials, but still some things are confusing me. And I got stuck in following part:

```
while (<KOEFICIENTYfile>) {
    @_=(split(/\s+/, $_));
    push(@ZAID,shift(@_));
    $KOEFICIENTY{$ZAID[-1]}=[@_];
}
```

As I understands this part then it:

1. Reads line from filehandle `KOEFICIENTYfile`
2. Separates them by spaces (one or more)
3. Loads first item from this separated array into array `ZAID` (and in the process, removes it from `@_`)
4. ??? Adds a rest of a separated array into array `KOEFICIENTY`? I am confused by curly brackets part and by square brackets after equals sign.

I think that I understood the meaning of `@`, `$`, `@_` or negative indexing but this is beyond me. Can you please advice me on meaning of this?

Comment: All suggested answers was helpful and each had some interesting point in it, but as accepted answer i chosen @Disco 3´s answer since it was descriptive, helpful and suggested `Data:Dumper`. Anyway, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[-1]` indexing is just a shortcut way to say "last element of the array".

KOEFICIENTY is actually a hash (you can tell this because it is using curly braces, instead of square ones, around the index), so you're putting the rest of the array @_ into a hash called KOEFICIENTY with a key of the last element of the array.

If you include:

```
use Data::Dumper
```

at the top of the script and do

```
print Dumper(%KOEFICIENTY)
```

it will nicely format the output for you, which may help

Answer (score 1):

The original coder was trying to be too clever using the negative offset.  It would have been much more obvious if the code had been written with a simple temporary variable thus:

```
while (<KOEFICIENTYfile>) {
    @_ = (split(/\s+/, $_));
    my $key = shift(@_);
    push(@ZAID, $key);
    $KOEFICIENTY{$key} = [@_];
}
```

The braces on `$KOEFICIENTY` show that this is a "hash" of key/value pairs named `%KOEFICIENTY`, and not a normal array.

If you don't actually need to preserve the sort order of the keys you could just use `keys %KOEFICIENTY` to retrieve them instead of storing them in `@ZAID`.

Comment: So what are the braces? (`{...}`)

Answer (score 0):

`@zaid` is a list, into which the first part of the split is added.

`%KOEFICIENTY` is a hash, in which a reference to the rest of the split is stored as a list reference under the key of the first part.

So if the line is `a b c`, `@zaid` will get `a` and `%KOEFICIENTY{'a'}`  will hold a reference to a list containing `b` and `c`.